# Как найти самый короткий маршрут?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть несколько городов 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8... но прямого маршрута между каждым нету. Чтоб попасть в 8й с 1го, нужно поехать через 3,5 и 6й. Как найти самый короткий маршрут?

Comment: Ваша попытка решения в студию!

Comment: я не пробовал ее решить, мне интересен алгоритм

Answer (score 4):

Это классическая задача на графах. Она решается при помощи алгоритма Дейкстры.

Comment: зачем сразу Дейкстры, здесь граф не взвешенный, обычного BFS хватит.

Comment: @pavel - граф взвешенный, все ребра весят 1. BFS найдет все маршруты, затем придется среди них искать оптимальный.

Comment: не совсем, просто Дейкстры сложность минимум `N log N` а то и `N^2` а лобовой BFS работает за `N`. И искать не все маршруты, а только 1 самый (он будет оптимальным).

Comment: @pavel, bfs работает за O(n+m) либо O(n^2) в зависимости от реализации. Дейкстра за O(n^2). За O(n*lb(n)) вроде есть похожий алгоритм, но это не совсем дейкстра.

Comment: @gbg, bfs как раз ищет оптимальный.

Comment: @Qwertiy BFS за O(n+m) Дейкстра без кучи O(n*n + M) c кучей O(M  + N log N).

Comment: @pavel `+m` не может быть при матрице смежности.

Comment: @Qwertiy матрица не может быть быстрее списка смежности. Но в любом случае BFS быстрее :)

Answer (score 0):

Задача может решаться с помощью алгоритма А*